# How to animate toggled class with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I want to do some simple transition/animation using React and CSS.
The idea is to click on image and that will toggle new section down below, I would like to make a nice transition when toggle.

This is my React:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

 <div className="box" id="box" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
      <img src="myImage" />
 </div>
```

And the section that toggles:

```
{show && (
          <div className="transform popup">This text will show!</div>
)}
```

Toggling the div works perfectly fine, but the animation does not.

CSS for animation:

```
.popup {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}

.transform {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}

.transform-active {
    background-color: #45cee0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Normally with jQuery I would use something like this

```
$("#box").click(function() {
  $('.transform').toggleClass('transform-active');
});
```

How can I re-write into react friendly ?

Comment: Have you tried adding / removing the class rather than show / hide it? Such as `className={show ? "displayPopup" : "hidePopup"}` where `.displayPopup` will have your css transform style and `hidePopup` will simply `display: none` ?

Comment: Yes, but the transition/animation still does not work.

Comment: I figured that this is more of a CSS issue than a javascript one, you should make a proof of concept where a new test `<div>` serves as your transition element, no javascript just the animation to see if it really works on its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using @keyframes for css animation. This should work. :)

```
// react component
const [boxVisibility, setBoxVisibility] = useState(false);

const showNewBox = () => {
    setBoxVisibility(!boxVisibility)
}

return(
    <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => showNewBox()}>Edit</button>
        {boxVisibility && <div className="show-box">
            <q>I am the new guy</q>
        </div>}
    </div>

);

// css here
@-webkit-keyframes SHOW-BOX {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes SHOW-BOX {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes SHOW-BOX {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes SHOW-BOX {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.show-box {
    -webkit-animation: SHOW-BOX 2s ease;
    -moz-animation: SHOW-BOX 2s ease;
    -o-animation: SHOW-BOX 2s ease;
    animation: SHOW-BOX 2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you set initial width and height to zero you could keep your div “mounted” and just toggle desired class as you did using jQuery. It could be:

```
    <div className={`transform popup ${show ? 'transform-active' : ''}`}>
        This text will show!
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jirka, this is just showing/hiding but no transition animation :(